# Can bad software/web app architecture compromise my 2FA key?

Tags: authentication, multi-factor

So this is a two part question:

1) When I have a compartmentalized system, and then I use the same hardware 2FA key for 2FA across all compartments, can my hardware key be used to trace me through the compartments and link my compartments together?

2) Can a poorly designed application (native) or a web app, compromise my key in anyway?

Comment: for 1, are you saying you use the same exact 2FA key?  Are we talking a physical token here or a 2FA app like Google Auth which has a unique key per app.

Comment: The hardware USB key or the Physical Card. Sorry for the discrepancy.